# JavaScript cannot locate one specific element by ID on page when all others work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have an odd issue using JavaScript to find an element by ID.  No function will run against it because the selection is undefined.  It has the same kind of definition as many on the same page.  There is only one element by this ID.  And, when I assign an ID to the surrounding paragraph, it works just fine.  So, the problem is bypassed. But, I am very curious as to the problem.  I am showing the pertinent items.

This JavaScript is part and parcel of a Rails application, so it is included as an external file using application.js.  It's a large file with many functions and they all work except when referencing this one ID.  And, as I stated, I select many other ID's on this page in the same fashion with no issue.

I use RubyMine and have searched the entire application for conflicts and typos related to the issue.  There are no conflicts and every expected reference to item_message is found.  item_message is included in a partial along with other references that JavaScript locates easily.  I searched for syntax errors before it was included and none are found.  I reordered the items on the page and in JavaScript to no avail.  I simply don't know why this doesn't work.

When I tried to hide the element using class optional, that worked.  However, it also hid other items that should not have been hidden.

It's working like this:

HTML:

```
  <p id="item_message_p">
  <input class="string optional form-control" placeholder="Message? (optional)" type="text" name="item[message]" id="item_message"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var item_message_p = $('#item_message_p');
select_item_spot_id.change(function () {
    var spot = $(this).val();
    if (spot != "") {
      $.getJSON('/spots', {spot: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
        if (data.name.toLowerCase() === 'sold') {
            item_message_p.hide();
        } else {
            item_message_p.show();
        }
      })
    }
});
```

It wouldn't work like this, as var item_message is undefined:

HTML:

```
  <p>
  <input class="string optional form-control" placeholder="Message? (optional)" type="text" name="item[message]" id="item_message"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var item_message = $('#item_message');
select_item_spot_id.change(function () {
    var spot = $(this).val();
    if (spot != "") {
      $.getJSON('/spots', {spot: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
        if (data.name.toLowerCase() === 'sold') {
            item_message.hide();
        } else {
            item_message.show();
        }
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this based on your code. [`#item_message` is defined.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrr6j98x/)

Comment: @Andy Interesting.  My console shows it undefined.  Unexpectedly, so.  Good to know.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the only element on the page with that ID?

Comment: @Andy Absolutely certain.  Checked and double checked.  Even searched the entire application for use of that name.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andy Gosh, I hate it when I do that...  Searching code doesn't help much when the ID is internally generated.  Yes, there are two on the page and the first one is being hidden.  The console showed undefined at one point, probably as I was making changes.  Doggone it.  Please post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Adding an answer isn't really worth the effort :) Glad I helped tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Andy's suggestion, I ended up checking the generated page to find that another element had generated the same ID.  That explains the issue.  Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page is loaded before looking up elements. So wrap your code in `$(function () {...});`, like this:

```
$(function () {
    var item_message = $('#item_message');
    select_item_spot_id.change(function () {
        var spot = $(this).val();
        if (spot != "") {
          $.getJSON('/spots', {spot: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
            if (data.name.toLowerCase() === 'sold') {
                item_message.hide();
            } else {
                item_message.show();
            }
          })
        }
    });
});
```

This will make your code execute when the `dom` is ready.

Also, it is best to close your `input` tag explicitly:

```
<input ..... />
```

Notice the slash. This absence might also explain the issue, including the spoil-over effect you noticed when hiding the element.

Comment: Yes, I do have that in my file.  I only showed the directly pertinent parts.  I should have mentioned it, but it could be assumed in that all other references work fine.  Thanks for your input..

Comment: Added a second observation about closing the input tag

Comment: That might explain it.  Will test.

Comment: Well, that did not help.  In fact, the closing slash was gone when the page was rendered even though other changes, such as the JS, were loaded.  So, I know it was all refreshed.  It's also only valid in HTML5, from what I see.  Darn, I was hoping...

Comment: Is there any possibility you could provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Another thing to exclude a potential problem: could you put the `id` attribute as the first one in your `input` tag, so before `class` ... etc, and see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `select_item_spot_id.change()`, but `select_item_spot_id` is not defined. You defined `item_message` or `item_message_p`. You might like to do it inside a onDOMReady event listener, as spotted by @trincot . This example code works for me:

```js
$(function () {
   var item_message = $('#item_message');
   var select_item_spot_id = $('#select_item_spot_id');
   select_item_spot_id.change(function () {
      var spot = $(this).val();
      // DEBUG
      if(item_message.length > 0)
         alert('works!');
      // END DEBUG
      if (spot != "") {
         $.getJSON('/spots', {spot: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
            if (data.name.toLowerCase() === 'sold') {
               item_message.hide();
            } else {
               item_message.show();
            }
         });
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <select id="select_item_spot_id" name="select_item_spot_id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <input class="string optional form-control" placeholder="Message? (optional)" type="text" name="item[message]" id="item_message">
</p>
```

Comment: I appreciate the input but select_item_spot_id is not part of the issue and is external to it.  As I mentioned, the code worked in one case and not the other and select_item_spot_id was involved in both cases.  Inserting that code would simply raise more similar issues.  Thanks...

Comment: I added `select_item_spot_id` to the example so it can demonstrate it works with the fiddle/code snippet. Taking only this part of the code, it never fails. So it might be another problem outside this tiny part of code what is making it don't work, as you already found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972347/javascript-cannot-locate-one-specific-element-by-id-on-page-when-all-others-work/33972761#33972761 .